# SSL settings in rabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, iot

I have installed rabbitMQ on my system with a static IP and a domain name as well. I used letsencrypt to generate SSL certificates for rabbitMQ but rabbitMQ doesn't work when I enable SSL port

I have used the following config settings:

```
listeners.ssl.default = 5671
ssl_options.verify=verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert=false
ssl_options.cacertfile = (path to cacert.pem)
ssl_options.certfile = (path to cert.pem)
ssl_options.keyfile = (path to key.pem)
```

Is there any other settings which are left or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Letsencrypt only generates domain validation certificates (see https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/) which work in a web server - are you using websockets? (so the web server can use your LetsEncrypt certificate)